# Method overload in typescript brings error

Tags: typescript

I tried to use method overload, but it throws an error at second overload declaration, I wan't to figure out why.

```
class A {
  set(item: B | C): void;
  set(item: B[] | C[]): void; // error: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration

  constructor() {}

  set(item: any) {
     if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      //...
    } else {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Sure I can separate it, but want to know why compiler throws error.

**Interesting thing** - if I remove `constructor` there woun't be error.

Comment: [I am unable to reproduce this in the playground.](https://tsplay.dev/wjnZMw) You should include more code and a minimal reproducible example (preferably as a playground).

Comment: Move that constructor below set.

Comment: After you've updated your question, the problem is pretty clear. As the error message says, the implementation is not immediately following the declaration.

Comment: _"but want to know why compiler throws error."_ Why something works the way it does in technology does not always lead to satisfying answers. How it works is good to know. In this how it works is that the implementation must immediately follow the overload signatures. Why it works that way could be anything including "it was easier to write the compile with that assumption and sort of makes logical sense that way anyway."